# Referencing a text like a hyperreference inside a document

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a table with many entries and I want to reference the key so another person can quickly look up what the key means.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
Table
snippet1\label{?key1} & longexplanatory text
snippet2\label{?key2} & longexplanatory text
snippet3\label{?key3} & longexplanatory text

connect \ref{key1} with \ref{key13}
```

After compilation I want the text to read

```
connect snippet1 with snippet3
```

The reader should be able to quickly jump to the table when clicking on `snippet-N`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following uses `\refstepcounter` (instead of the internal `\@currentlabel`) of a dummy counter to make the text to something that can be referenced. `\raisebox` moves `\refstepcounter` a bit to move the anchor position, if package `hyperref` is used. At the place of `\refstepcounter` `hyperref` sets the anchor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{keylabel}
\newcommand*{\keylabel}[2]{%
  \leavevmode
  \raisebox{2ex}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \renewcommand*{\thekeylabel}{#1}%
    \refstepcounter{keylabel}%
    \label{#2}%
  }%
  #1%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\keylabel{snippet1}{key1} & longexplanatory text\\
\keylabel{snippet2}{key2} & longexplanatory text\\
\keylabel{snippet3}{key3} & longexplanatory text\\
\end{tabular}

connect \ref{key1} with \ref{key3}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]